# Postfix not printing all the status=sent logs in /var/log/maillog?

Tags: email, postfix, logging, log-files

We have configured a postfix mail server, it takes email IDs from a CSV file, which has 13,500 recipients. The email is sent to all the recipients at a time, but in `/var/log/maillog` we only get around 5500-7500 entries of delivery status `status=` daily, most of these(almost all) are `status=sent`.
We have NOT used a remote syslog, the logs are printing in the same box.

Is it the normal behavior of postfix? Means any time limit or some other limit? If yes, how to get all the logs?
OR Are we missing something?

Update:  As per queries in a comment from @digijay
*Did you also check for status=deferred and status=bounced?*
Yes, sometimes we got these status also

*Anything in mailq at the end of the day?*
Nothing.

*Also, are you sure your script that sends the mails works correctly?*
Yes, it is working properly.

Comment: Did you also check for `status=deferred` and `status=bounced`? Anything in `mailq` at the end of the day? Also, are you sure your script that sends the mails works correctly?

Comment: Did you check for instances where a single email is sent to everyone at a particular domain name?

Comment: Hi Michael, glad to see you again! (OT)

Comment: @MichaelHamptonIt is not to a particular domain name. It includes hundreds of domains.

Comment: @MichaelHampton was reffering that when an email is send to multiple addresses at the same domain, postfix will make one single session to send that email to multiple users. E.g. if you send one email to user1@example.com and user2@example.com it will not split it in different emails. The splitting in multiple mail boxes is done by the destination MTA.

Comment: @MirceaVutcovici, is that means - we will only get some email status of every domain in maillog? eg. if we simultaneously send 500 to gmail.com domain and 600 to yahoo.com domain, then we may miss some emails in logs?